# How to handle strings in VC++?

Tags: string, visual-c++

HI,

Once we accept an input from a keyboard, How can we add that character into a string in VC++?

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::string` from STL, and the + or += operator.

To do this, `#include <string>` and use the class `std::string`.

After that, there are various ways to store the input from the user.

First, you may store the character input directly into the string:

```
std::string myStr;
std::cin >> myStr;
```

Second, you can append the input to an existing string:

```
std::string myStr;
myOtherStr += myStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  s += " ok";
  std::cout << s;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
std::string inputStr;
std::cin >> inputStr;
```

This code will accept a string typed on the keyboard and store it into `inputStr`.

My guess is that you're in the process of learning C++. If so, my suggestion is to continue reading your C++ book. Keyboard input will surely be addressed in some upcoming chapter or the other.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to go about, depending of what you exactly need. Check the C++ I/O tutorial at this site: [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/)