# How to add character into a string(using vc++)?

Tags: string, visual-c++

I'm trying to create a text editor in vc++, without using mfc's edit class. I've managed to capture the key pressed using WM_CHAR message, but now how can i add it into a string(or any character handling data type) so that i can display it in my client area using TextOut() or functons similar to it???

Comment: Can you provide more info, what's the type of variable that holds the string? it matters

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251320/how-to-handle-strings-in-vc asked by same questioner 20 mins ago. To the questioner, if you want to add detail to a question, edit the original - do not ask an almost identical new one.

Answer (score 0):

if it's a plain char array then you can use

```
your_str[strlen(your_str)] = ch;
```

where ch is the character.

Watch our for running out of space in your_str

Comment: sorry for asking an unclear question, once i get to know which key has been pressed(inside the WndProc, using WM_CHAR message and then using its wparam to know the key), what should i do to display it in my client area??.

Comment: @Arun I'm not GDI expert but I think after you add the char to your string you should invalidate your editor area, this will lead to you getting a WM_PAINT so you can repaint the string again.